# Erlang SMTP client WITH attachments

Tags: smtp, erlang

I'm looking for one of two things:

1. An Erlang library that supports sending of emails with attachments
2. An example of using gen_smtp to send an email with an attachment, since I have already successfully sent emails with this library

It seems there is very little in the way of SMTP client support with attachments out there, although there are plenty of modules that can send plain text emails via SMTP. Anyone have suggestions?

Also, using Windows - I'm not sure the sendmail route is available?

---

*Agus, when I try that exact code, as well as similar code, I keep getting the following error, any ideas?:*

```
** exception error: {badmap,[]}
     in function  maps:get/3
        called as maps:get(content_type_params,[],[])
     in call from mimemail:ensure_content_headers/7 (c:/temp/erlang/myapp/_build/default/lib/gen_smtp/src/mimemail.erl, line 667)
     in call from mimemail:encode/2 (c:/temp/erlang/myapp/_build/default/lib/gen_smtp/src/mimemail.erl, line 161)
     in call from email_test:send_email_with_attachment/0 (c:/temp/erlang/myapp/src/email_test.erl, line 14)
```

The version of gen_smtp I'm using in rebar.config:

`{gen_smtp, ".*", {git, "git://github.com/gen-smtp/gen_smtp.git", {branch, master}}}`

Comment: Please see to the updated answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: you **can** use gen_smtp to send an email with attachment.

If you have used `gen_smtp_client:send(Email, Options)` or `gen_smtp_client:send_blocking(Email, Options)`, then you can actually generate the `Body's Email` variable using `mimemail:encode/2`.

```
%% @doc Encode a MIME tuple to a binary.
encode({Type, Subtype, Headers, ContentTypeParams, Parts}, Options) ->
...
```

Below code shows how to send message with email inline body and 2 attachments (`test1.txt` and `erlang.png` respectively). The key here is to use `multipart/mixed` MIME type and construct the email body accordingly.

```
send_email_with_attachment() ->
    From = "noreply@mydomain.com", 
    ToList = ["target_email@mydomain.com"],
    
    Part2Filename = "/tmp/test1.txt",
    {ok, Part2Binary} = file:read_file(Part2Filename),
    
    Part3Filename = "/tmp/erlang.png",
    {ok, Part3Binary} = file:read_file(Part3Filename),
        
    Email = mimemail:encode(
                            {
                             <<"multipart">>, %%Type, 
                             <<"mixed">>, %%Subtype,
                             %%Headers,  
                             [
                              {<<"From">>, <<"No-Reply <noreply@mydomain.com>">>},
                              {<<"To">>, <<"target_email@mydomain.com">>},
                              {<<"Subject">>, <<"Mail Subject">>}
                             ], 
                             #{}, %%[], %%ContentTypeParams, 
                             %%(Multi)Parts
                             [
                                %%Part 1: this is the inline mail body, note the {<<"disposition">>, <<"inline">>} tag
                                {
                                     <<"text">>, %%Type, 
                                     <<"plain">>, %%Subtype,
                                     %%Headers
                                     [],
                                     %%ContentTypeParams
                                     #{
                                       disposition => <<"inline">>
                                       },
                                     %%Part
                                     <<"Email body (inline) is here blah blah..">>
                                },
                                
                                %%Part 2: this is the text file as attachment, note the {<<"disposition">>, <<"attachment">>} tag
                                {
                                     <<"text">>, %%Type, 
                                     <<"plain">>, %%Subtype,
                                     %%Headers
                                     [],
                                     %%ContentTypeParams
                                     #{
                                       disposition => <<"attachment">>,
                                       disposition_params => [{<<"filename">>, <<"test1.txt">>}]
                                      },
                                     %%Part
                                     Part2Binary
                                },
                                
                                %%Part 3: this is the PNG file as attachment, note the {<<"disposition">>, <<"attachment">>} tag
                                {
                                     <<"image">>, %%Type, 
                                     <<"png">>, %%Subtype,
                                     %%Headers
                                     [],
                                     %%ContentTypeParams 
                                     #{
                                       disposition => <<"attachment">>,
                                       disposition_params => [{<<"filename">>, <<"erlang.png">>}] 
                                      },
                                     %%Part
                                     Part3Binary
                                }
                              ]
                            },
                            [] %%Options
                           ),
    Opts =  [{relay, "smtp.mydomain.com"},
              {tls, never}
             ], 
    gen_smtp_client:send({From, ToList, Email}, Opts).
```

**This is what you will see in the mailbox**:

[image: On Email Client]

Comment: Agus, this is an excellent representation of what I need to put in the body. But when I try exactly this code and another similar example, I always get this error (see my edit for full error) - do you have any ideas?

`** exception error: {badmap,[]} in function  maps:get/3`

Comment: Apparently we are using different code-base version; there was some changes on the function parameters- the latest one is using `maps` instead of `list` for ContentTypeParams. I have updated the answer to reflect this change.